# Webview scrolling/dimension issues when is inside complex layout

Tags: android

I have this layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/back"
>

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<ImageView android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>


<WebView 
    android:id="@+id/htmlView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

/>

</ScrollView>
```

Webview is just for displaying html formatted text, I do not need any special function.
Problem is that I do not get a scrollable layout, but something like this:

---

textview (big, about 30% of layout, not scrollable)

---

image (big, about 50% not scrollable)

---

tiny scrollable webview

---

where's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may help you......

```
parentScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        Log.v(TAG,"PARENT TOUCH");
                        findViewById(R.id.webView).getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
                    {
                        Log.v(TAG,"CHILD TOUCH");
                         //  Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```